# Angular 10 error when setting value from select

Tags: java, arrays, angular, typescript, arraylist

I want to change the role of a user. I have a user table and a role table with a ManyToMany relation. I can get all the values and also get the right selected value, but I can't update it.

The User model:

```
export class User {
constructor(
    public id: number,
    public firstname: String,
    public lastname: String,
    public username: String,
    public password: String,
    public roles: Role
) { } }
```

The Role model:

```
export class Role {
constructor(
    public id: number,
    public name: String
){}}
```

The Edit component:

```
export class AdminEditUserComponent implements OnInit {

  roles: Array<Role> = [];
  users = [];

  constructor(private _adminService: AdminService, private router: Router) { }

userForm = new FormGroup(
    {
      id: new FormControl(this._adminService.getUser().id),
      firstname: new FormControl(this._adminService.getUser().firstname, Validators.required),
      lastname: new FormControl(this._adminService.getUser().lastname, Validators.required),
      username: new FormControl(this._adminService.getUser().username, Validators.required),
      password: new FormControl(this._adminService.getUser().password),
      selectedRole: new FormControl(this._adminService.getUser().roles, Validators.required)
    }
  );

  getRoles(): void {
    this._adminService.getRoles().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.roles = result;
      }
    )
  }

  initfunc(): void {
    this.getRoles();
    this._adminService.getRoles().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.roles = result;
      }
    )
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initfunc();

    this._adminService.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
      this.roles = [... new Set(users.map(user => user.roles))];
      console.log(this.roles);
  })
}

submitted: boolean = false;

  onSubmit() {
    let rolToUpdate = new Role(this.userForm.get("selectedRole").value, "");
    let userToUpdate = new User(this.userForm.get("id").value, this.userForm.get("firstname").value, this.userForm.get("lastname").value, this.userForm.get("username").value, this.userForm.get("password").value, rolToUpdate);

    this.submitted = true;

    this._adminService.putUser(userToUpdate).subscribe();

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.router.navigate(["/admin/users"]);
    }, 1000);
  }

  btnReturn() {
    this.router.navigate(["/admin/users"])
  }

}
```

This is my html:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <select formControlName="selectedRole" class="form-control">
                <option *ngFor="let role of roles" ngValue="{{role.id}}" selected="{{role.id}}">
                    <div ngValue="role">{{role.name}}</div>
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

When I get the role from the database, this is how it's shown in json:
[image: the image]

And when I try to update it, it's like this:

[image: the image]

This is the error I get when trying to update:

```
JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.HashSet<com.example.f1codingbackend.model.Role>` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.HashSet<com.example.f1codingbackend.model.Role>` out of START_OBJECT token↵ at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 161] (through reference chain: com.example.f1codingbackend.model.User["roles"])
```

You can see that role array is not how it's supposed to be when updating. Can somebody please explain to me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Something I think you need to change, is the  element inside the  element in the html. You don't have to use this  element you need to use the `{{ role.name }}` only. so your code must be as follows:

```
<option *ngFor="let role of roles" ngValue="{{role.id}}">
    {{ role.name }}
</option>
```

Next, when you update/change the role, you get the ID of the new role (selected role)

`let selectedRoleID = this.userForm.get('selectedRole').value;`

Now you get the full Role object first:

use `let selectedRole = this.roles.find(role => role.id == selectedRoleID);`

Now you can use the `selectedRole` in your http request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I'm a step closer now, but it still doesn't work. When updating how do I get the Role object in an array? I think if it's not in an array the update doesn't work.

Comment: Well  I think you can declare it as an array from the beginning.
In the user model instead of using `public roles: Role` you can use `public roles: Role[];`
Second: you can replace the ordinary select element by a multiple select dropdown menu.
[primeng/multiselect](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/multiselect) 
This link leads you to the primeng library, it is a reliable library for every day use while working on angular. You can use it to select multiple role at the same time.
And of course it uses an array as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Basically When you get json from database, the roles are multiple so its showing as array in angular, but when you are trying to update it, you are passing only Role object, so try to pass it using array
like..

`{ "firstName" : "David", "lastname" : "lim", "roles" : [{"id" : 1, "username" : "david@gmail.com"}] }`

May this will help you..